# htmlagilitypack, не выводятся данные

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Хочу сделать поиск по картинке, посредством гугла, но при запуске выходит ошибка в строке inner, которая указывает на то, что `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.GetElementbyId(...) вернул null..` В браузере через консоль выводил содержимое по этому пути, все отображалось нормально. В чем моя ошибка?

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://pp.userapi.com/c837337/v837337779/68ff1/iXLxWEmoOoA.jpg";
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
            string inner = doc.GetElementbyId("topstuff").ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Скорее всего, на картинке " + inner);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем закрывать вопрос? Ответы на тот вопрос меня ни к чему не привели.

Comment: Как ни к чему? Теперь вы знаете, что нужного вам элемента нет на странице.